# Pass hidden parameters from URL in SSRS report in native mode

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I am trying to pass parameters via URL in SSRS report(2012) in native mode. URL looks like this:
`http://servername/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/xyz/rep_name&rs:Command=Render&ProjectUID=123&ProjectName=project_name
&WLReport=True`

I tried putting `rp:` before each parameter name, that didn't work either.

On setting parameters to visible and entering the values manually, the report renders perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. 
(Replace Reports with ReportServer in the URL and Reports.aspx with ReportViewer.aspx)

http:// servername/**ReportServer**/Pages/**ReportViewer**.aspx?ItemPath=/xyz/rep_name&rs:Command=Render&ProjectUID=123&ProjectName=project_name
&WLReport=True

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the reportserver URL instead of the reporting manager URL if you call the report directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx